# Menu 'title' transition with pop-out effect

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm dealing with an interesting problem now. I have a menu which consists of nested list inside a list. Something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <ul id="sub-menu">
      <li class="sub-menu-item">
         <div class="icon"></div>
         <span class="title">Icon title</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Span element with a class `title` is supposed to be hidden off screen and should pop-out on hover. My problem is, that I can't force this popping-out span to '*slide*' underneath the both menus.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dallows/6xt0qe29/.).

What am I doing wrong? I didn't design the page I'm just trying to make it work.

Note:
The class '**icons**' is the reminiscent of the older version in which user was able to switch between icons or text displayed in the menu.

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround. Instead of hiding the **title** `span` off screen I changed it visibility to hidden and show it on hover. The only problem is that the text is shown without transition effect and it looks bad when transition is slower.

```
span.title {
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #3a5fcd;
  line-height: inherit;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
  width: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

&:hover, &:focus {
  span.title {
    left: 100%;
    width: auto;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
    width: 10em;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Here is the link to updated [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/dallows/6xt0qe29/6/)